# Why is Target < Blockhash?

Tags: hash, difficulty, python

I am currently trying to validate a blocks hash against its target in python3:

This is a [block](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/bcy/test/blocks/000055f67563d1c2cb141d06d52d2fca63ef457c553519aeb635a2643a9af0b1) in the Blockcypher testnet, and I am using this [formula](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_is_difficulty_stored_in_blocks.3F) from the Bitcoin Wiki.

```
block_hash = '000055f67563d1c2cb141d06d52d2fca63ef457c553519aeb635a2643a9af0b1'
bits = '520159231'

target = hex(int(bits) * (2**(8 * (0x1b - 3))))
hash_ = hex(int(block_hash, 16))
print(target, hash_)
>>> 0x1f00ffff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0x55f67563d1c2cb141d06d52d2fca63ef457c553519aeb635a2643a9af0b1

if not target >= hash_:
    print('False)
else:
    print('True')
>>> False
```

Point is, that target is less than blockhash. But this should not be the case.
**Can anyone help me?**

Thank You for Your time.

Comment: That's because that target is represented in compact format: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#target-nbits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you convert the difficulty bits to hex you will get:
`0x1F00FFFF`

Coefficient = `0x00FFFF`

Exponent = `1F = 31`

Target = `Coefficient * 2**( 8 * ( exponent-3 ) )`

Target = `0xFFFF` with `31 - 3 = 28` trailing NULL (`0x00`) bytes

Target:
`0x0000FFFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Your Hash:
`0x000055f67563d1c2cb141d06d52d2fca63ef457c553519aeb635a2643a9af0b1`

So your POW fulfils the target.
Just to be sure, you might want to check endianness during your conversions between int/literal/hex types.